# CORS request is not allowed with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access an API from an Angular JS controller using the following code:

```
$scope.getOperators = function() {
    $scope.CSVData.forEach(function(entry) {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $http({
            url : 'http://api.pts.se/PTSNumberService/Pts_Number_Service.svc/json/SearchByNumberList?numbers=' + number,
            method : 'get'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
};
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.pts.se/PTSNumberService/Pts_Number_Service.svc/json/SearchByNumberList?numbers=76-3095686. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

From what I did understand, I know that CORS request should be enabled from the server, but at the moment the request is sent from the client side.

Am I missing something?

Comment: thats you servers job to fix that.

Comment: the resource on there is going to have to send the right headers down.

Comment: You are missing the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the server side. Take a look here : http://blog.bulte.net/12-24-2013/angular-wordpress-cors.html

Answer (score 1):

The **server** proivdes CORS support. You'll need to enable it there.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Ideally you'd replace the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to just domains that you want to allow or else anyone could access the api remotely / from their servers.

Comment: Problem is that the server's not mine. The server is `api.pts.se` and probably they haven't enabled CORS.

Comment: Well in that case you can't perform requests. You'll have to proxy through PHP.